# How do I align the text in line with the picture?

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying align the text inline with an image.

Here is what I have tried so far:

**HTML:**

```
 <ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
li
{
list-style-image:url(http://evenimente.academiasuccesului.ro/wp-content/themes/responsive/images/1.png);
margin-left:50px;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/japzzgpq)

This is close to what I want, although there is text on the bottom and I am trying to align it to be in the center.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a background image. Aligning the text and using line-height. There are plenty of answers on SO explaining different approaches. You need to browse and try what fits better your needs.

```css
    ul li {
        background-image: url(http://evenimente.academiasuccesului.ro/wp-content/themes/responsive/images/1.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        line-height: 70px;
        padding-left: 80px;
    }
    
    ul {
       margin: 50px;
       list-style: none;   
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use background image

```css
li{
  width: 68px;
  height: 68px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 68px;
  display: block;
  background-position: top left;
  background-size: 68px 68px;
  background: url(http://evenimente.academiasuccesului.ro/wp-content/themes/responsive/images/1.png);
  text-indent: 86px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
</ul>
```

or use pseudo elements

```css
li {
  position: relative;
  height: 68px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 20px 40px;
  line-height: 68px;
}
li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -70px;
  top: 0;
  width: 68px;
  height: 68px;
  display: block;
  background-position: top left;
  background-size: cover;
  background: url(http://evenimente.academiasuccesului.ro/wp-content/themes/responsive/images/1.png);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
</ul>
```